# I have an error when sending mail from the programming language C#

Tags: c#, email, smtp, port, smtpclient

I am sending emails from a C# method, where from one moment to another it stops working and I allow access to my host.

I have not uploaded changes to production, for a long time and I have even less touched this part of the code. I get the following error but I don't know what it means and what solution to give about it:

> Error: IoException:
> Handshake failed due to unexpected packet format

Code:

```
string mailFrom = emailSettings.Correo;
string nameFrom = emailSettings.Nombre;
string passwordFrom = emailSettings.Password;
string hostSMTP = emailSettings.HostSMTP;

// Message data
MailAddress fromAddress = new MailAddress(mailFrom, nameFrom, Encoding.UTF8);
MailAddress toAddress = new MailAddress(mailDestino, nombreDestinatario, Encoding.UTF8);

// Specify the message content.           
using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
{
    Subject = asuntoMensaje,
    SubjectEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
    IsBodyHtml = true,
    Body = cuerpoMensaje,
    BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8,
    Priority = MailPriority.Normal,
})
{
    // SMTP Cliente
    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient
                {
                    Host = hostSMTP,
                    Port = 587, 
                    EnableSsl = true,
                    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(mailFrom, passwordFrom),
                    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
                    Timeout = 2 * 60 * 1000 //2 minutos
                };

    message.Headers.Add("Disposition-Notification-To", mailFrom);
    message.Headers.Add("Return-Receipt-To", mailFrom);

    // Send the E-Mail
    smtp.Send(message);
}
```

Thank you very much, I look forward to your response.

Comment: Have you tried MailKit/MimeKit? [Microsoft recommend it over SmtpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.mail.smtpclient?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Code always does the same. It does not spontaneously change.
So, if you say that nothing has been changes on the code in the lasts months. The issue must  lay outside of your application.

I'm not saying that your application is perfect and you do not need to make adjustments to make it more robust, but my first step would be to investigate the mailserver itself.